# Expression cron every day between 12 and 2 p.m

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, cron

I would like to launch my aws lambda every day between 12 and 2 pm.

Could you tell me how to write the cron expression?

Thank

Comment: `0 * 12,13 ? * * *`!? https://www.freeformatter.com/cron-expression-generator-quartz.html

Comment: What do you mean by "launch my AWS lambda every day"? Do you mean _continuously_ throughout that time, or do you just mean that it should run at 12pm and stop at 2pm?

Answer (score 0):

```
* 0-59 12-13 * *
```

Every second from 12:00PM to 5:00AM, i.e., 3:00:00AM to 4:59:59AM

Have you seen the documentation
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/services-cloudwatchevents-expressions.html ?
I find it helpful, please check it as well